no such file or directory when initializing app
I am submitting a spark app to YARN on EKS, I will show what I think is the relevant configuration.
spark.yarn.stagingDir: file:///project/fs/apps/spark

When I submit the app I get the following:

org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: chmod: cannot access '/project/fs/apps/spark/subprojectname/.sparkStaging/application_1728900890114_0014': No such file or directory

When I ssh to both the resource-manager and node-manager(s) as root user (which is the value of env var CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user) I can access the shared fs /project/fs/apps/spark/, so I don't see the problem.
I don't have much knowledge of YARN, what is the process which is suppose to create the Spark application staging dir: .sparkStaging/application_1728900890114_0014?
Because obviously that process is failing to create the dir.
I know I did not post much information, but the app is HUGE and I don't know what additional information would be relevant.

Solved, so the issue was basically that i had the following setting:
park.hadoop.fs.defaultFS: s3a://a-bucket-in-my-account
So the stagingDir configuration should have point to s3 rather than shared FS
Was: spark.yarn.stagingDir: file:///project/fs/apps/spark
Should be: spark.yarn.stagingDir: s3a://a-bucket-in-my-account/project/fs/apps/spark
